# Unable to Debug using GDB in QtCreator

Tags: c++, mingw, qt-creator

I am working on a GUI based video processing project using Qt and opencv but since I am wncountering lots of app crashes I need to debug the code. I am using mingw4.4 and Qt creator but every time i try debugging Windows says gdb.exe has stopped working and detailed as :

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: gdb.exe
  Application Version:  0.0.0.0
  Application Timestamp:    49a7f7bd
  Fault Module Name:    msvcrt.dll
  Fault Module Version: 7.0.7600.16930
  Fault Module Timestamp:   4eeaf834
  Exception Code:   c0000005
  Exception Offset: 000143f9
  OS Version:   6.1.7600.2.3.0.256.1
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1: 0a9e
  Additional Information 2: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
  Additional Information 3: 0a9e
  Additional Information 4: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
```

I am using Windows 7 32 bit...

Answer (score 1):

Download and install newer version of gdb from http://www.equation.com/servlet/equation.cmd?fa=gdb and change debugger paths in Qt options for changes to take effect...

Comment: Adding 5.1.1 instead of 4.8.5 worked for me :) Thanks!